# Como puedo actualizar un jpanel

Tags: mysql, netbeans, java-swing, aplicación-escritorio, jdatechooser

Tengo un formulario de varios paneles y en cada sección tengo jdatechooser los cuales cuando hago un registro en mi base de datos, modifico o elimino no me permite hacer mas cambios en el jdatechooser.

Por ejemplo entro a la sección de abonos lleno los campos y doy de alta el registro y lo hace como se debe de hacer.

El problema es que a la hora de hacer otro registro o una segunda modificación, mi jdatechooser deja de funcionar y no me permite escribir o seleccionar ninguna fecha y si me salgo de esa sección y entro a clientes y regreso otra vez a mi sección de abonos funciona otra vez con normalidad. Lo que necesito es que dentro del mismo botón de altas después de ejecutar todo el registro, actualice o refresque el jpanel para que este bug que tengo con el jdatechooser no suceda cada que hago un nuevo registro.

Este es el código de mi botón de alta

```
         if(txtIdAbono.getText().isEmpty()) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El campo id esta vacio");}\n
         else if (txtNombre.getText().isEmpty()) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El campo nombre esta vacio");}\n

         else if (txtImporte.getText().isEmpty()) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El campo importe esta vacio");}\n

         else if (txtObservaciones.getText().isEmpty()) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El campo observaciones esta vacio");}\n

         else if (CalendarFecha.getDate() == null){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No se ha seleccionado una fecha");}\n

         else if (cmbProveedor.getSelectedItem()=="Seleccione un proveedor"){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Seleccione un proveedor"); }\n

         else if (cmbObra.getSelectedItem()=="Seleccione una obra"){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Seleccione una obra"); }\n

         else{            
            try {                
                String valueP=cmbProveedor.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String valueO=cmbObra.getSelectedItem().toString();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String date = sdf.format(CalendarFecha.getDate());
                String usuario = Login.usuario.getText();                
            PreparedStatement pps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO abonos(id, nombre, proveedor, obra, importe, observaciones, fecha, usuario) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            pps.setString(1, txtIdAbono.getText());
            pps.setString(2, txtNombre.getText());    
            pps.setString(3, valueP);
            pps.setString(4, valueO);
            pps.setString(5, txtImporte.getText());
            pps.setString(6, txtObservaciones.getText());
            pps.setString(7, date);
            pps.setString(8, usuario);
            pps.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos guardados");
            mostrartabla("");//Muestra la actualización de los datos en la tabla                        
            limpiar();//Limpia los campos una vez guardados los datos
            
        }
            catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(pnlAbono.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ya existe un registro con este id");
        }  
             catch (SQLException e) {
             Logger.getLogger(pnlAbono.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e + " No se pudo dar de alta el registro, hay un problema con el botón alta");
                } 
            }
```

Comment: Esta pregunta es igual a la otra que creaste? Si es igual, por favor no abras varias preguntas iguales, que eso no va a ayudar a que te respondan más rápido. Recuerda también que puedes editar una pregunta usando el enlace Editar que está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Esta versión de la pregunta ya tiene el código que has hecho; podrías cerrar la otra si es igual y atender los comentarios e intentos de respuesta en esta. Gracias! :)